# Every function in $D'(\Omega)$ is the limit of a sequence in $D'(\Omega)$ with compact support.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, weak-convergence

How will we prove that for every $f\in D'(\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $(f_j)$ in $D'(\Omega)$ with compact support such that $f$ is the limit of $(f_j)$?

Comment: Thank you.  I'll delete my comment that was made obsolete by my edit.

Comment: I want to add that $D'(\Omega)$ satisfies the completeness property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K_n$ be a sequence of compacta with $K_n\subset K_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} K_n = \Omega$. Let $\chi_n\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\chi_n(x)=1$ for $x\in K_n$ and $\operatorname{supp }\chi_n \subset K_{n+1}$. Then define $f_n=\chi_n f$.

For a test function $\phi$ you have $\operatorname{supp }\phi \subset K_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then for $n>m$ you have 
$$ f_n(\phi) = (\chi_n f)(\phi) = f(\chi_n\phi) = f(\phi).$$